# Can't get Qt Creator to Properly Compile OpenCV

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I am trying to compile a Qt project and it seems like OpenCV is having problems. From what I have read so far, this could likely be a compiler/linkage problem. I have tried a couple different compilers without any success. Other libraries seem to be fine (libtiff, STD, other Qt libraries), but OpenCV is causing problems. I haven't for the life of me been able to make any progress on fixing it, any suggestions would be much appreciated. Posted below are things that I believe might be valuable in finding a solution.

Qt Makefile (.pro):

```
QT      += core gui multimedia widgets multimediawidgets opengl
TARGET   = LAUWebCalTag
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        laumemoryobject.cpp \
        lauwebcamerawidget.cpp \
        lauvideosurface.cpp \
        lauvideoglwidget.cpp \
        laucaltagglwidget.cpp \
    laucaltagglobject.cpp

HEADERS += \
        laumemoryobject.h \
        lauwebcamerawidget.h \
        lauvideosurface.h \
        lauvideoglwidget.h \
        laucaltagglwidget.h \
    laucaltagglobject.h

RESOURCES += lauwebcameracapture.qrc

CONFIG(release, debug|release):DEFINES += QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT

win32 {
    INCLUDEPATH   += $$quote(C:\Users\Sam\Downloads\opencv\build\include) $$quote(C:/usr/include)
    INCLUDEPATH   += $$quote(C:\Users\Sam\Downloads\tiff-4.0.9\tiff-4.0.9\libtiff)
    DEPENDPATH    += $$quote(C:\Users\Sam\Downloads\opencv\build\include) $$quote(C:/usr/include)
    LIBS          += -L$$quote(C:\usr\libs) -lopengl32
    LIBS          += -L$$quote(C:\Users\Sam\Downloads\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib)
    LIBS          += -L$$quote(C:\Users\Sam\Downloads\tiff-4.0.9\tiff-4.0.9\libtiff) -llibtiff_i
    CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -lopencv_world310
    CONFIG(debug, debug|release):   LIBS += -lopencv_world310d
}
```

Issues:

[[Screenshot of Resulting Compile Issues]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVSBt.png)

Build and Run:

[[Build and Run Kit Options]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Oaox.png)

[[CMake (Not 100% sure if CMake is necessary for this project or right)]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jp5ku.png)

I also thought the way cv:: was being declared was strange for this:

```
 namespace cv
 {
    using std::vector;
 }
```

I apologize for the dumb question, I am brand new to both Qt and OpenCV

Comment: since you're using 32-bit, perhaps the OpenCV you've installed is 64-bit.

Comment: OpenCV needs to be properly configured and built with specific options. From the list of linker errors it seems some feature was not enabled for OpenCV.